# Scrapy - flow of the Crawl spider

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm having a hard time figuring out how Scrapy works (or how I need to work with it).
This question is a bit broad - more for understanding.

I setup a CrawlSpider and threw in 6 start urls.
From those (24 items to scrape on each of those start urls) I expected roughly 144 rows to end up in my database, but I only have 18 now.

So I'm using

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
```

to avoid complication with Rules for now.
Now Scrapy should take those 6 urls and crawl them and then process the items on those pages.
But instead it seems as if it takes those 6 urls and then checks each link on those pages and follows those links first - is this possible?
Does Scrapy just take URL 1, scan all links and follow everything allowed?
When does it take URL 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your answer in the [official documentation page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order), but for completeness I will paste it here:

> By default, Scrapy uses a LIFO queue for storing pending requests,
>   which basically means that it crawls in DFO order. This order is more
>   convenient in most cases. If you do want to crawl in true BFO order,
>   you can do it by setting the following settings:

```
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1 
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

**Note:**
The way you describe the crawl order is usuall called [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (depth-first search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (breadth-first search). Scrapy uses DFO and BFO ('O' is for 'order', but the meaning is the same).

Comment: Ah yes - very good. Hard to search for it without know the right keywords (LIFO/DFO/BFO/etc.) got it working. Had to `from scrapy import squeue` which isn't documented on that page.
But now the results are looking better.